# What is the difference between using and include in c++?

Tags: c++

I know that include is for classes and using is for some built-in stuff, like namespace std... When you include something, you can create objects and play around with them, but when you are "using" something, then you can use some sort of built-in functions. But then how am I supposed to create my own "library" which I could "use"?

Comment: Both are for classes and both are for built-in stuff.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply put `#include` tells the pre-compiler to simply copy and paste contents of the header file being included to the current translation unit. It is evaluated by the pre-compiler.

While `using directive` directs the compiler to bring the symbol names from another scope in to current scope. This is essentially put in effect by the compiler.

> **But then how am I supposed to create my own "library" which I could "use"?**

Namespaces are something which are used for preventing symbol name clashes. And usually every library implementer will have their functionality wrapped up in one or many namespaces.

Answer (score 7):

'include' basically does a copy-paste the value of a file to the location of the "include" line. This is used to make your source code (usually .c file) aware of a declaration of other source code (usually sits in .h file).

'using' basically tells the compiler that in the next code you are using something (usually a namespace) so you won't have to do it explicitly each time:

Instead of:

```
std::string a;
std::string b;
std::string c;
```

You could write:

```
using namespace std;
string a;
string b;
string c;
```

Comment: You could, but you shouldn't. `using namespace std;` completely defeats the purpose of namespaces. It often leads to mysterious-looking problems. `std` is there for a reason. Use it.

Comment: Yeah, I know this, but still, what is the purpose of operator "::" (what does it mean?) in this case and also what is std, what does it include apart cout, cin and that kind of basic stuff? How can I put some of my classes into those namespaces?

Comment: @user2030383: `::` is the scope resolution operator which tells the compiler in which scope(*namespace/class/struct/union*) it can find the particular symbol. There are a lot of symbols which are part of the `std` namespace, `std` stands for *standard* library namespace, You will need to see the documentation to exactly see which all symbols are defined in it. You should not put your classes in `std` namespace, it is undefined behavior if you do so.Instead you should wrap your classes in your own namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You can say both gives the same functionality but #include is not done by compiler where as using is done by compiler. In #include all the code is placed in file where #include is given where as namespace gives the definition of function and variables from one scope to another. If you have function with same name in two header files and both are included then there will be an error of redeclaration but you can use same name functions if they are from different namespaces.